# Ubuntu One software no longer works

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I open Ubuntu One software it does not sync:

[image]

Pressing **Edit personal details online** results in this dialog box:

[image]

Pressing **Edit your services online** results in this page:

[image]

with an addres which seems to be offline.

Pressing **See details** opens nowhere:

[image]

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

2 days ago, Canonical closed down Ubuntu One file services. For more info, [here](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) is the blog post

Comment: It says *The current services will be unavailable from 1 June 2014*. btw I didn't know that!